# SCSS darkmode switch background color not working

Tags: javascript, sass, hugo

i started implementing a dark-mode-toggle for my website, using Hugo, SCSS and JS.

So far I created a mapping for both of the theme-modes "light" and "dark" and used them within my other scss-files with @include

Now all the separate colors are switching fine with the toggler, except my background-color. Couldn't find any solution so far, but maybe I have to interfere somehow with Bootstraps JS? Any ideas?

**SCSS**

```
$primary-font: "Raleway", sans-serif;
$icon-font: "themify";
// Color Variables
$primary-color: #3787b3;
$black: #000;
$white: #fff;
$gray: #f4fcff;

$themes: (
  darkTheme: (
    'bg-color': #222222,
    'text-color': #ffffff,
    'text-color-dark': #c9c9c9,
    'text-color-light': #ffffff,
    'body-color': #3b3d42,
    'border-color': #4a4b50
  ),
  lightTheme: (
    'bg-color': #fff,
    'text-color': #666666,
    'text-color-dark': #222222,
    'text-color-light': #959595,
    'body-color': #fff,
    'border-color': #acb9c4
  )
);

@mixin theme() {
  @each $theme, $map in $themes {
    $theme-map: $map !global;
    .#{$theme} & {
      @content; 
    }
  }
  $theme-map: null !global;
}

@function theme-get($key) {
  @return map-get($theme-map, $key);
}
body {
  @include theme(){
    background-color: theme-get('bg-color');
  }
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**JS**

```
    //theme-toggler
    const getTheme = window.localStorage && window.localStorage.getItem("theme");
    const themeToggle = document.querySelector(".theme-toggle");
    const isDark = getTheme === "dark";

    if (getTheme !== null) {
      document.body.classList.toggle("darkTheme", isDark);
    }

    themeToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
      document.body.classList.toggle("darkTheme");
      window.localStorage &&
        window.localStorage.setItem(
          "theme",
          document.body.classList.contains("darkTheme") ? "dark" : "light"
        );
    });
    console.log()
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ with .Site.LanguageCode }}{{ . }}{{ else }}en-US{{ end }}">
    {{- partial "head.html" . -}}
    <body>
        {{- partial "preloader.html" . -}}
        {{- partial "header.html" . -}}
        {{- block "main" . }}{{- end }}
        {{- partial "footer.html" . -}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {} ?

Comment: hey thetailor, not sure how this would help me. I am looking more for a default light-theme and if the user wants he/she can switch the theme-mode with a switch (toggler) button. @media is linked to browser-preferences or am I wrong? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

Comment: Yeah you're right. Could you maybe make a codepen or something so the code is easily testable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You js toggle targets the body tag, but the CSS is added to html.
If you make two changes to your SCSS it ought to work :)

```
    @mixin theme() {
        @each $theme, $map in $themes {
            $theme-map: $map !global;

            //
            // 1. move the & (will be body) first 
            //
            &.#{$theme} {
                @content; 
            }
        }
        $theme-map: null !global;
    }

    //
    // 2. include the theme in the body selector
    // 
    body {
        @include theme(){
           background-color: theme-get('bg-color');
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:
`!global` should be avoided from now on
If defined in the root, the function `$theme-get` doesn't like that it might get a null as map. Not sure how to deal with it as a beginner.

```
@function theme-get($key) {
  @if ($theme-map != null) {
     @return map-get($theme-map, $key);
  }
  @return red;
}
```

Not sure how to continue with that...